# Is it possible to inherit css class?

Tags: html, css

I have two css classes:

```
magrin{
    margin-top:35px;
    background-color:red; 
}

#MainContent {
    margin: 0 .3em;
    font-size: .8em;     
}
```

Is it possible to make #MainContent class inherit magrin class?

Comment: Neither of those are css classes

Comment: there are css classes but not the ones you're thinking of

Comment: CSS doesn't have classes. Things which people (incorrectly) call "CSS classes" include HTML classes, CSS class selectors, CSS selectors in general, and CSS rulesets.

Comment: You can (kind of) inherit from HTML side? Class and id...

Answer (score 4):

[No](http://dorward.me.uk/www/css/inheritance/).

CSS inheritance is from parent *element* to child *element*, not from one ruleset to another.

You can write your styles using a grouping selector, apply multiple classes to a single element, or use a preprocessing tool such as SASS or LESS.

In this case, a grouping selector (`,`) would probably be the best fit:

```
#MainContent {
    margin: 0 .3em;
    font-size: .8em;     
}

#MainContent, magrin{
    margin-top:35px;
    background-color:red; 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Class inheritance is possible with SASS. You may want to check it out, works like this:

```
.magrin{
    margin-top:35px;
    background-color:red; 
}

.MainContent {
    @extend .magrin;
    margin: 0 .3em;
    font-size: .8em;     
}
```

Read more in http://sass-lang.com/guide

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as far as I know. But you make `magrin` a class by adding a `.` to the beginning of the rule, you can add it to your element with the ID `MainContent`.
IDs must be unique, but an element can have both an ID and one (or several) class(es).

Answer (score 0):

you can apply `magrin` styles on `#MainContent` like this

```
magrin, #MainContent {
    margin-top:35px;
    background-color:red; 
}

#MainContent {
    margin: 0 .3em;
    font-size: .8em;     
}
```