# Creating the simplest HTML toggle button?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create the simplest possible HTML toggle button, but I'm having a hard time finding exactly how to do this.

As far as I can see, there is no direct support for toggle button in HTML, the only thing I found is an ARIA attribute "aria-pressed" recommended for that purpose here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/button_role#toggle_buttons

So, I came up with the following example with just a `<button>` with an `aria-pressed` attribute which works, in the sense that the JavaScript handler console.log prints out true, then false, then true etc - that is, it shows toggling, but only of the 'aria-pressed' attribute - the look of the button is not changed at all!

Now, the thing is, when I use a `<button>` as below, with no CSS at all, the button inherits some browser styling defaults; in Firefox at least, I can see (slight) changes in button gray color if I hover (mouseover) the button, and yet some more changes if I click the button and hold it pressed.

So, what I'd like for my "simplest" button, is simply to inherit the existing browser default styling for a "pressed" button, and have the button be styled like that for as long as the 'aria-pressed' attribute is true. Preferably, I would not want to write *any* specific CSS to style the button (as in specific background color etc) - all I want is for the button to inherit the browser defaults for a pressed button, when rendering a "toggled" button when its 'aria-pressed' attribute is true.

Is there any way to achieve this, and if so, how?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>test</title>
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <button type="button" id="btn-my-toggle" aria-pressed="false">Click me, a toggle button</button>
</body>

<script>
  function on_my_toggle_btn_click(e) {
    //console.log(e, this); // `e` is `click { target: button#btn-my-toggle ... }`;  `this` is `<button id="btn-my-toggle"...`
    let isPressed_str = this.getAttribute('aria-pressed'); // note, typeof here is String!
    let isPressed = (isPressed_str === 'true'); // "cast" to Boolean
    isPressed = !(isPressed); // toggle
    this.setAttribute('aria-pressed', isPressed);
    console.log(this.getAttribute('aria-pressed'));
  }

  let my_toggle_btn = document.getElementById('btn-my-toggle');
  my_toggle_btn.onclick = on_my_toggle_btn_click;
</script>

<html>
```

Comment: `<input type="checkbox">` is the UI element designed for this.

Comment: Thanks @Quentin - I have encountered "checkbox" in my searches, but I had a hard time finding someone explicitly saying that it is the UI element designed for this; feel free to post it as an answer

Comment: How would you defined "simple"?

Comment: @NIco - "simple" in the sense of not having to define any CSS for my element at all, just inheriting browser defaults (maybe at most, if possible, just saying something like "have the style of browser 'pressed' button applied, when the button is toggled"

Comment: In short to answer your question you're looking for a native input element that represents on/off, and that's what [a checkbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox) does. Checked on or checked off. Note that you'll see toggle switches on sites nowadays (mainly due to their inclusion in component libraries) which represent on/off but they aren't native elements and, for accessibility (and sanity) reasons, [should probably be avoided](https://axesslab.com/toggles-suck/). A simple checkbox is perfect. @sdbbs

Comment: Just out of curiosity... what is the actual purpose of that button? What is that you're building? This might be as well an XY-Problem: *"I want this"* without explaining what you're actually after. In knowing what's the end task might cleanse the drawing board eentirely.

Comment: "*I had a hard time finding someone explicitly saying that it is the UI element designed for this*" Are you expecting someone to define what a checkbox is and how it works? You can find the definition of that input type at https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#checkbox-state-(type=checkbox) if you are curious.

Answer (score 1):

A [checkbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox) is the simplest and most semantic way to create a an interactive element that a user can toggle "on" or "off".

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="my-toggle">
<label for="my-toggle">toggle me</label>
```

If you want it to visually appear as a button, you can style it with CSS. Here's an example from the [Bootstrap CSS framework](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/forms/checks-radios/):

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="my-toggle" class="btn-check">
<label class="btn btn-primary" for="my-toggle">toggle me</label>
```

Comment: Any specific reason for not doing `<label><input type="checkbox" id="my-toggle"> toggle me</label>`

Comment: @mplungjan None, other than that's not the pattern Bootstrap uses in their docs and I wanted to make both examples consistent. I personally prefer the wrapping label syntax. But semantically they're equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

This is simpler if you do not want to use a checkbox (like here https://alvarotrigo.com/blog/toggle-switch-css/)

```js
document.getElementById('btn-my-toggle')
  .addEventListener('click', (e) => e.target.closest('button').classList.toggle('pressed'))
```

```css
#btn-my-toggle { border: 1px solid black;} 
#btn-my-toggle.pressed { border: 1px solid red;}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="btn-my-toggle">Click me, a toggle</button>
```

You can toggle the aria-pressed like this:

```js
document.getElementById('btn-my-toggle')
  .addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const tgt = e.target.closest('button');
    tgt.classList.toggle('pressed');
    tgt.setAttribute('aria-pressed', tgt.matches('.pressed'))
  });
```

```css
#btn-my-toggle {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#btn-my-toggle.pressed {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="btn-my-toggle">Click me, a toggle</button>
```

Comment: `e.target.matches('.pressed')` is bug prone. I cannot stress this enough on the importance on `Event.currentTarget`. `target` should be used like `Event.target.closest(selector)`. `target` should be also used where explicitly where an API (still at this date) does not implements the `currentTarget` (like i.e: in Observer APIs)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan You are of course correct. Corrected

Comment: Seems like it's indeed a tricky concept to master :) Your examples are better now, but since you don't use Event delegation, and to prevent DOM roundtrips you can simply use `e.currentTarget.classList.toggle('pressed')` - since `currentTarget` (without delegation) is assured to be the Element on which the listener is assigned to (the button itself). (Offtopic - it's also a good practice to avoid single-character argument names; `ev`, `evt`, `event` are more expressive, verbose, easily searchable)

Comment: This practice should be avoided. It's preferred to minimise the risks of breaking the business logic if a semantically unsignificant change is introduced in HTML. The code is more reusable when you use `Event.currentTarget` or `Event.target.closest(selector)`-for dynamic Evt. delegation. `Event.target`, `Event.target.matches()` etc. should be avoided in the context of evt. handlers and their usage teachings. `Event.target` should be used only for debugging or in specific APIs or if you really, really know what you're doing. Not something to bump in front of novice developers as a BP technique.

Comment: So what would you use as a boolean here: `tgt.setAttribute('aria-pressed', tgt.matches('.pressed'))`

Comment: I am not talking about `tgt.matches('.pressed')` but about what you had before: `e.target.matches(".pressed")`.

Answer (score 0):

After considering the responses here, I guess the summary is, that what I want cannot really be achieved -  but of course, there are workarounds.

Let me be slightly more specific: it's been some decades since I've studied UI, but maybe as a consequence of that, when I look for a "toggle button", I indeed look for something that looks like a button, and when its toggled, it looks like a "constantly pressed" button.

That is why I have a mental difficulty in accepting that I should use a checkbox for this purpose, even if it is intended by design: as per comment by @Quentin:

> `<input type="checkbox">` is the UI element designed for this.

While I do accept that -- for me, a check box is still a "check" in a "box", and when toggled off, the "check" disappears - and in my mind, this is not a "button" (visually speaking).

Furthermore, I do not use HTML often, and so, if - as in this case, - I need a "toggle button", I would prefer just to grab whatever the browser defaults are for "toggle button" and work with those, instead of thinking whether `{ border: 1px solid #0e0a02;}` is readable for me or not (and I indeed can get sidetracked in these things, and here I'd prefer I do not).

So, the problem here is that even if I end up accept having to use `<input type="checkbox">` - then I'm forced to thing about custom styling and `{ border: 1px solid #0e0a02;}` ( see e.g. [Style checkboxes as Toggle Buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15436450/style-checkboxes-as-toggle-buttons) ) which I wanted to avoid in the first place.

Taking a step back: I know that the browser has style defaults for rendering a `<button>` when it just sits there - then also a style for when the button is hovered (mouse-over'ed), and a style for when the button is pressed (and held).

So, if I could say: "have this button rendered as 'pressed', in case the toggled attribute is true", I'm all set - I don't have to write custom CSS, and I'd have inherited the default browser styling. But can I say that?

Apparently not:

[Any way to keep an html button pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238314/any-way-to-keep-an-html-button-pressed)

> > Is there any way to keep it visually pressed and unpress it via javascript
>
> There is no way to do that with javascript.
>
> But you can use javascript to simulate that effect by adding/removing a css class, or directly editing the css properties you have chosen to use.

So, I thought, if I could just get to whatever CSS styles the browser has for `<button>:active` (the pseudo-style when pressed), and used that as a "base CSS" class to "inherit" from, that would be good - but:

[Is it possible to inherit css class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43092537/is-it-possible-to-inherit-css-class)

> [No](http://dorward.me.uk/www/css/inheritance/).
>
> CSS inheritance is from parent element to child element, not from one ruleset to another.

There goes that approach too; and finally, I went back to the accepted answer of [Any way to keep an html button pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238314) :

> > I have a button ... Is there any way to keep it visually pressed and unpress it via javascript?
>
> I would try CSS and use the border-style inset, personally.

Now, `border-style: inset` is NOT how the browser (at least firefox) renders `<button>`'s `:active` (that is, `<button>` pressed) - but it's the bare minimum I can have, without having to worry about CSS styling the *rest* of the button, and inheriting whatever the browser defaults are.

So then, I can just use the approach in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/button_role and add a CSS rule for the `aria-pressed` attribute - and I also changed the `role` to my own custom "togglebutton"; and with that, I have:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>test</title>
  <style>
[role="togglebutton"][aria-pressed="true"] {
  border-style:inset;
  border-radius:4px;
}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <button type="button" id="btn-my-toggle" role="togglebutton" aria-pressed="false">Click me, a toggle button</button>
</body>

<script>
function on_my_toggle_btn_click(e) {
  //console.log(e, this); // `e` is `click { target: button#btn-my-toggle ... }`;  `this` is `<button id="btn-my-toggle"...`
  let isPressed_str = this.getAttribute('aria-pressed'); // note, typeof here is String!
  let isPressed = (isPressed_str === 'true'); // "cast" to Boolean
  isPressed = !(isPressed); // toggle
  this.setAttribute('aria-pressed', isPressed);
  //console.log(this.getAttribute('aria-pressed'));
}

let my_toggle_btn = document.getElementById('btn-my-toggle');
my_toggle_btn.onclick = on_my_toggle_btn_click;
</script>

<html>
```

... and now I have a toggle button, which is semantically a `<button>`, and which for the most part inherits the browser styling defaults for this element, and I did not have to style manually via CSS (beyond the `border-style:inset;`, and also the `border-radius` to make it look the same as the default button display of Firefox).

Comment: Your question asks for the simplest toggle button. The approach above necessitates HTML, CSS, _and_ JS—as well as ARIA to track state. I didn't downvote, but surely my [answer that uses only HTML and CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76837247/5351721) is objectively simpler while equally satisfying semantics and accessibility.

Comment: funnily enough I did write a version with `[aria-pressed="true"] {}` but disliked it in favour of classList.toggle since it is an actual toggle. Then it  sort of took on a life of its own